# The discrete probability density of $Z=XY$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables. 
 
$X$ : Bernoulli with $\frac{1}{4}$ success parameter 
$Y$ : Bernoulli with $\frac{1}{2}$ success parameter 

 
Calculate the discrete probability density of  $Z=XY$ 
$$P(Z=0)=P(\{X=0\} \cup \{Y=0\})= \\=P(X=0)+P(Y=0)-P(X=0, Y=0)=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{8}=\frac{7}{8} \\
P(Z=1)=1-P(Z=0)=\frac{1}{8} \\ 
$$

Why must I  subtract the quantity $P(X=0, Y=0)$ for calculating $P(\{X=0\} \cup \{Y=0\}) $? 
In this case, is $ \cup $ like  XOR? 
Is there any statistical theoretical concept? 

 
I know that : 
$ E \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} $ is a discrete set 
$f: E \rightarrow [0,1] $ : $$\sum_n f(x)=1 $$ is the discrete probability density on $E$

Thanks

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an application of the rule: $\mathsf P(A\cup B)=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)$

The measure of a union is the sum of the measures of the events minus the measure of their intersection.   Because you don't want to double count the overlap.

Union, $\cup$, is analogous to inclusive-or, $\vee$.   It is the event of $A$ or $B$ happening (or both).

Answer (score 1):

For events $A, B$ in a sample space (in a $\sigma$-algebra, etc.), recall
$$P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)\text{.}$$